# Passing query string and else-if statement

Tags: if-statement, request.querystring

```
        echo $_REQUEST['status'];
    if ((isset($_REQUEST['status'])) && ($_REQUEST['status'] == "signin" )){

    echo "do this";

    } elseif ((isset($_REQUEST['status'])) && ($_REQUEST['status']) == "forget")){

    echo "do that";
 }
```

The code not working... Kindly let me know where I am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Means not working properly... the above code showing signin and forget box both for first condition and showing none for the second condition.

Comment: As, I am passing the values to the LOGIN page as <a href="login.php?status=signin">LOGIN</a> and <a href="login.php?status=forget">FORGET PASSWORD</a>

Comment: yes, its a simple syntax... missing something. Any solution?